# Hide div if Eval value of control is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to hide the div containing the RadBinaryImage if the bind value "Pic" is null?

```
<div class="photo-container">
 <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" DataValue='<%# Eval("Pic") == DBNull.Value? new System.Byte[0]: Eval("Pic") %>'
 AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Width="300px" 
 AlternateText='<%#Eval("PicName") %>' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

visible attribute will return false if the value is null and it will return true if the value is not null.

---

```
<div class="photo-container" visible='<%# Eval("Pic") == DBNull.Value ? false : true %>'>
 <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" DataValue='<%# Eval("Pic") == DBNull.Value? new System.Byte[0]: Eval("Pic") %>'
 AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Width="300px" 
 AlternateText='<%#Eval("PicName") %>' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just try this:

```
<div class="photo-container" visible="<%# Eval("Pic") == DBNull.Value%>">
</div>
```